# jquery Mobile ajax xml post

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

can this work for xml parsing as i have parse using json but it is not showing any response from web service.
**this is the status of webservice**
*http/1.1 405 method not allowed 113ms*

```
 $j.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   async: false,
   url: "Service1.asmx",
   dataType: 'XML',
   //contentType:'application/json',
   success: function (data) {
     $j.each(data, function (index, element) {
         alert("Successful here: " + element);
         //$j('#json').append("<li'>"+element+"</li>");
     });
   }
}).done(function (data) {
 console.log(data);
 alert("XML Data: " + data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your method name in the `url` parameter of ajax as eg: `url: "Service.asmx/ConversionRate"`

And if you are calling a webservice which is in different domain Eg: Your .js file in which you are writing ajax function is in `www.abc.com` and you are calling a web service in `www.xyz.com` (i.e) cross domain call, then you need to use server-routed proxy as shown below or use jsonp as cross domain call is not allowed by browsers.

```
var url = 'http://www.webservicex.net/Service1.asmx/ConversionRate;
var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from xml where url="' + url + '"') + '&format=json&callback=?'; 

 $j.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   async: false,
   url: yql,
   dataType: 'XML',
   //contentType:'application/json',
   success: function (data) {     
     if(data.query.results){
        var result = data.query.results.double.content.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');
        $j.each(result, function (index, element) {
         alert("Successful here: " + element);
         //$j('#json').append("<li'>"+element+"</li>");
     });
    }
   }
});
```

Use either `success` or `done` function, as both of them serve the same purpose.

And if you are using service from the same domain then the above said server-routed proxy not needed. Then the code will be as follows.

```
 $j.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   async: false,
   url: "Service1.asmx/GetConversion",
   dataType: 'XML',
   //contentType:'application/json',
   success: function (data) {          
        $j.each(data, function (index, element) {
         alert("Successful here: " + element);
         //$j('#json').append("<li'>"+element+"</li>");
     });
    }
});
```

Comment: thankx alot its working so can you please tell http 500 error